# Transform Dataset so it can be used as training set for Classify

Tags: dataset, machine-learning

Trying to learn the new `Dataset` features, I am playing with the `iris` dataset:

```
iris=SemanticImport["http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv"];
iris[1;;3]
```

[image: this is only a subset of iris]

Now I would like to use `Classify` to predict the Species from the other Variables. From the documentation of `Classify` it seems I need to write a query that outputs something like

```
{{{5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2} -> "setosa"}, {{4.9,3.,1.4,.2} -> "setosa"}}
```

and so on. But here I am stuck. How do I write this query function? I tried

```
trainQuery = Function[row, 
   Rule[row[All, 1;;4], row[All, 5]]
];
```

but this fails.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: And what is the source of the `iris` dataset? It's *not* available from `ExampleData["Dataset"]`.

Comment: Good point. Added source for `iris`.

Comment: @m_goldberg, it's actually built-in: `ExampleData[{"Statistics", "FisherIris"}]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
iris[1 ;; 5, {Most@# -> Last@#} &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use `Normal` to get it out as a `List`

```
Normal @ iris[1 ;; 5, {Most@# -> Last@#} &]
```

> ```
> {{{5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2} -> "setosa"}, {{4.9, 3., 1.4, 0.2} -> "setosa"},
>  {{4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2} -> "setosa"}, {{4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2} ->  "setosa"},         
>  {{5., 3.6, 1.4, 0.2} -> "setosa"}}
> ```

To do it for all rows simply:

```
Normal @ iris[All, {Most@# -> Last@#} &]
```

**Note**: if you have to use it with `Classify` there's still one more step. `Flatten`:

```
Flatten[Normal @ iris[All, {Most@# -> Last@#} &], 1]
```

And if that's the case, the `Flatten` may be avoided all together by using `Sequence`

```
Normal @ iris[All, Sequence[Most@# -> Last@#] &]
```

**Update**

As per your question in the comments, you can use `Association` with `Classify` like this:

```
Classify @ Normal @ iris[Map[Association], Sequence[Last@# -> Most@#] &][Merge[#, Identity] &]
```

Or just use operator forms and `Composition`

```
Classify @ Normal @ iris[Map[Association] /* Merge[Identity], Sequence[Last@# -> Most@#] &]
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! Do you think it is possible to apply `Classify` without converting to a list? I tried `<| Most@# -> Last@#|>&` but this is not accepted by `Classify`.

Comment: @KarstenW. I haven't used `Classify` before, so I don't know anything about it. Sorry, I can look into it though.

Comment: @KarstenW., see my update. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it sure does. I still have to accommodate with this new `Dataset` feature, and start to see its elegance.. :-) Your examples help me understand.

Comment: @RunnyKine For what it is worth, Classify and Predict will both support the syntax `Classify[Dataset[...] -> colname]` in version 10.0.2.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon. Good to know. Any idea as to timeframe for the release of 10.0.2?

Comment: @RunnyKine: we're doing daily release candidates now, so soon!

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Ah exciting!. Thanks for the update, can't wait.

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference, here is the example for `Classify` I worked out with your help:

```
iris = SemanticImport["http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/data/iris.csv"];
iris = iris[All, <|
    "SepalLength" -> 1, "SepalWidth" -> 2, "PetalLength" -> 3, 
    "PetalWidth" -> 4, "Species" -> 5|>] 
trainIdx = RandomSample[Range[1, Length[iris]], Round[Length[iris]*0.9]];
trainSet = Normal@iris[trainIdx, Most@# -> Last@# &];
testIdx = Complement[Range[1, Length[iris]], trainIdx];
testVal = Normal@iris[testIdx, Last];

clss = Classify[trainSet, Method -> "RandomForest"];
pred = clss[Normal@iris[testIdx, Most]];
Print["RF: ", Count[MapThread[Equal, {pred, testVal}] , False]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I found it interesting to purposefully handicap the classifier by only giving it 50% of the data to train on, testing with the remaining 50%. Then looked at the results in a confusion matrix   .

Add this to the bottom of Karsten's code:

```
testSet = Normal@iris[testIdx, Most@# -> Last@# &];
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[clss, testSet];
cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

Yields:

[image]